# Weird results due to argument promotion when missing the prototype declaration in C

Tags: c, types, prototype

I have encounter a problem which can be summarized as follows,

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
        float f=23.45;
        printf("main: %f\n", f);
        t1(f);
/*    the result would be 
      main:23.450001 
      t1:2.000000    */          
}
void t1(float f)
{
        printf("t1: %f\n", f);
}
```

I know now that the weird behavior is due to missing of prototype declaration and the arguments are thus promoted,(float->double?),still i cannot figure out why the result is 2.000000,so can anyone give a more detailed explanation? I am using ubuntu10.04 gcc4.4.3

Comment: Missing the prototype declaration will keep it from compiling at all. But aside from that, I don't see the problem. I'm getting `23.450001` for both.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The behavior you are observing is specific to stack-based parameter passing. For people who compile 64-bit x86 code by default and are unable to reproduce it, you can try with "gcc -m32" instead of just "gcc".

With stack-based parameter passing, `t1()` read 32 bits from the stack, and these 32 bits happen to form the floating-point value `2.0`. 
At the call site, because `t1` did not have a prototype, the argument `f` was promoted to `double` and it was a `double` that was written on the stack (C99 6.5.2.2:6 “If the expression that denotes the called function has a type that does not include a prototype, the integer promotions are performed on each argument, and arguments that have type float are promoted to double. These are called the default argument promotions”).

There is no reason for `t1` to recover the intended value from the stack since it does not read it properly with the same type and width it was written.

Comment: When declaring f in main as double and comparing its value to the byte-wise representation of f in t1, the first 4 bytes do match perfectly. The double promotion seems to be right.

Answer (score 1):

Because the compiler does not know that `t1` takes a float, it promotes the float to a double. On your platform, `t1` interprets the first four bytes of that double as a float.

2.0 is represented as 1 x 2^0, which in binary is three zero bytes followed by a 64 (on x86-64). As it happens, 23.45 as a double has the same first four bytes, 0, 0, 0, 64 (followed by 51, 115, 55, 64). So if you take the double 23.45 and interpret the first four bytes of it as a float, you get 2.0.

Comment: I just managed to verify this. :) `double f = (float)23.45;
    cout << ((float*)&f)[0] << endl;`

Comment: Thanks very much,previously I cannot figure out why the it is exactly 2.0000, it turns out that i failed to take the endianness into consideration.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that a missing prototype implies the function will later be declared with int arguments, and that appropriate conversions take place. So, I assume if you replace the float by int in the declaration of t1, you'll get a result of 23.

Comment: A missing prototype does not mean all arguments are assumed to be of type int.

Comment: `23.45` is not converted to `int` at the call site, because if you change `t1(f);` to `t1(23);`, you do not get the same behavior. Plus the binary representation of 23 interpreted as a `float` is a denormal number, very close to 0, not `2.0`.

Comment: If no conversion happens, what /does/ happen at the call site? The type of the function argument is unknown, and I remember gcc warnings about such behaviour. OTOH, it's right that int 23 interpreted as float would be far removed from 2. Well, theory refuted.

Comment: @thiton In old versions of C, it was specified what happened. AFAIK these rules have been removed from C99.